# Issues with calling Redux dispatch from Formik onChange - Formik value doesn't save when dispatch is invoked

Tags: reactjs, redux, formik

We are trying to implement a Formik form, that uses a Redux store for some of the Select option values.

When a select field ("Country") is updated, we need to update the filteredStatesProvinces in the Redux store so that the options are associated with the newly selected country.

When I configure multiple invocations under the field's `onChange` event, the formik invocations succeed independently (i.e. if they are the only invocations called).  If I add a `dispatch(fetchStates(Country))` method or any other `dispatch` reference into the `onChange` event, the `formik.handleChange(e)` fails to actually set the field value.

`dispatch` is mapped to `useDispatch` from `react-redux` and is included above the form component in its parent.

Any ideas would be welcome, I have read the other posts on using Formik Context, the main goal is to find the simplest way to call `dispatch` from `onChange` or `onBlur`.

```
<TextField
  select
  fullWidth
  margin="dense"
  id="country"
  name="country"
  label="Jobsite Country"
  value={formik.values.country}
  onChange={(e) => {
    formik.handleChange(e);
    dispatch(fetchStateProvinces({ country: e.target.value }));
  }}
  onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
  error={formik.touched.country && Boolean(formik.errors.country)}
  helperText={formik.touched.country && formik.errors.country}
>
  {allCountries.map((option) => (
    <MenuItem
      key={option.abbreviation}
      value={option.abbreviation}
      selected={option.abbreviation === formik.values.country}
    >
      {option.name}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</TextField>
```

I tried:

- making `dispatch` async
- moving the `dispatch` into the input props for the form component
- changing the invocation order so that the `dispatch` invocation is after the `formik.handlechanges`,
- making the `onChange` call a separate function that handled both invocations
- changing the `dispatch` to do a nominal task (e.g. `resetState`) which wasn't API / async
- adding `formik.setFieldValue()` after the `dispatch` invocation

None of these resulted in formik setting the value for country in its values property, though the dispatched event did result in success every time.

It's as though the dispatch event prevents formik from completing its update/setFieldValue.

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of the two calls? (calling handleChange last) Have you verified that `formik` and `dispatch` are properly defined and in scope in this arrow function?